# Rename Wildlfy temporary content folder(s)

Tags: deployment, configuration, wildfly, war, vfs

As mentioned in the title, is there a way to rename Wildfly `tmp/vfs/temp/temp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/content-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy` folder(s)?

What I would like to obtain is something like this:

- `tmp/vfs/temp/temp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/WebApp.war`, where `WebApp.war` is the name of a WAR package inside the deployment folder

OR

- `tmp/vfs/temp/temp-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/WebApp.war-yyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`.

I tried looking in the Wildfly documentation, but I could not find anything useful.
I am pretty sure it is feasible and it should not be related to a configuration file inside the WAR package.

Currently I am using two versions of Wildfly (on different hosts): *8.1.0* and *10.0.0-Final.*

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: No, I dont think its possible. For this change you have to change backend code.

Comment: @Abhijit I saw it at least once (on a customer's host which I cannot connect to anymore). I'm confident they were using Wildfly 8.1.0. Are you saying that they edited Wildfly source code?